# New IIS Server redirecting to old server

Tags: iis-7

I have been tasked with re-homing sites off of our old Server 2008 host. I have sucessfully migrated all the sites but one.

we use a DNS Alias that points to the correct server so users are not constantly having to update book marks. On the old server if you http://SERVER1 you get the site, however on the new host it is redirecting back to the old server. If I go http://SERVER2/Portal I get the site.

I am able to do a nslookup, and can ping by hostname and that all is resolving fine.

I am at a loss, because everything in the IIS Configuration looks identical.

Thoughts on what the issue is?

Comment: Enable FRT and learn more about those 30x redirection responses please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Once you know where they come from, you can stop them.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try again, and what is Portal?

Comment: /portal is the virtual directory in IIS, and after clearing the cache for what seemed like the hundredth time, it started working.